# Does setting a object to null multiple times have a performance impact?

Tags: java

I am making a game in java that is using a 'tail' behind the mouse. I use a MouseMotionListener and use the mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) function to add locations of the mouse to an array.

So as long as the mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) function is fired, it should add the current mouse location to an array, when the dragging is stopped, the array should be cleared.

My idea was to use the mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) function to set the array to null. I can do this like this:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    if(myTailArray != null) {
        myTailArray = null;
    }
}
```

Or just like this:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    myTailArray = null;
}
```

The last method means that myTailArray will be set to null a lot of times for nothing. But does it make a difference performance wise?

EDIT: Just to be clear, I know this can cause bugs when the mouse isn't moved after a drag. I use a MouseListener to reset on the press and release of the mouse, but I was just curious.

EDIT2: Thanks for all the comments! I thought because the event is fired 'quite a lot' it maybe would be a bad smell in my code. Though I haven't thought about caching etc.

Comment: do it without the check.

Comment: The best way to answer any performance question is always to test.  You can write a sample app or two to test the different options and see for yourself.

Comment: You added that you "havent thought about caching, etc". Careful, you still may be missing the point. You didn't think about "caching, etc." and you *shouldnt*. Not in a mouse event handler. The *real* thing you didn't think about was actual performance requirements, profiling, and appropriate optimizations.

Comment: @JasonC You are absolutely right. The thing is that I like optimizing stuff, but I don't have much experience with it. I wasn't really worried that it would affect my program by much, just what kind of impact it had.

Comment: If you like optimizing stuff you should experiment with things where optimization has a higher impact. This article, although dated, may occupy you for a bit http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/03/20/optimization.html

Comment: @JasonC Thanks, I will be reading that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a non-volatile instance variable takes a negligible amount of time: it's just a local CPU cache write operation, without any expensive memory barrier instructions. Depending on circumstances, some writes may be completely eliminated by the JIT compiler.

But just to put these things into perspective, I should add that we are discussing 0.5 ns vs. maybe 10 ns worst-case scenario with full `volatile` write. Just *calling* the method may take more time than the write itself. A mouse generates 100 reports per second at most—that's 100 x 10ns = 1 µs of time taken (worst-case!) within each second of wall-clock time.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously not, as you had to come here and ask after being unable to notice a difference in your programs actual performance. :)

The point is, unless it isn't meeting your performance requirements, it isn't worth optimizing.

In any case, the performance difference of doing an extra assignment vs a branch is completely negligible compared to e.g. the time spent generating and handling a mouse move event.

Think about it (simplified):

1. User decides to move the mouse.
2. Users brain sends electrical impulse to muscles in arm and hand via chains of sodium/potassium reactions.
3. Force from muscle movement overcomes friction of mouse on table, mouse moves.
4. Optical mouse samples images on table, compares consecutive images in hardware and calculates an offset.
5. Movement data serialized and sent over USB, various synchronization occurs.
6. Hardware interrupts generated and handled, incoming data read, buffered, dispatched to appropriate driver.
7. Mouse position updated. Cursor redrawn by blitting and modifying blocks of data in video memory.
8. Window system checks its windows, checking mouse state and dispatching events to synchronized thread queues.
9. Swing window receives native events, checks own internal state, translates to Swing events and dispatches messages through object tree, eventually resulting in...
10. Your mouse move handler being called.

So why are you worried about a few nanoseconds difference in an assignment or a branch? Just the stack cleanup code in the method call itself will dwarf your assignment.

Edit: By the way, here is a somewhat dated but still valid great article about micro-tuning: http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/03/20/optimization.html

One of the key points there is "Always set a target before starting tuning, so that you know when to stop." Not only does the article have a nice case study you can work along with, it finishes with a nice outline of a general procedure: Identify the bottleneck, set a target, test, profile, and optimize accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing is a micro-optimization that you should not concern yourself with.  If there is a difference, it will be negligible, even if the method is invoked thousands of times.  It may not even be the difference you expect: depending on how often the value is null or non-null, the added branch instruction may outweigh the redundant assignment (branches are relatively expensive on many architectures).

Generally, attempting to optimize this sort of thing without having demonstrated a real-world performance issue is counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

If it has any impact at all You won't notice it anyway.

But the version without if statement should be "faster" as comparison is more expensive than assignment. (I remember that from uni Though can't find any reference to prove it)

Comment: I don't think this is a good thought, this way everything that makes a program just a tad slower is not worth to optimize. Which is kinda silly in my opinion. I didn't know that assignment was more expensive than comparison, thanks for that!

Comment: Actually, most things that make a program just a tad slower aren't actually worth optimizing. Optimizing code that already far exceeds performance requirements, and concentrating on areas that a reminiscence fractions of actual bottlenecks, are both highly counterproductive. Your users will spend more time waiting for you to finish and test your software then they'd ever lose by waiting an extra 10ns for a mouse movement.

Answer (score 0):

The only case where the second (and generally preferred) approach would be slower would be in an intensely-multithreaded environment where redundantly setting to null results in changed pages and resulting cache thrashing.  It happens, but if you were in that situation you'd very likely already be aware of the potential problem.